# Storing values instead of printing them with AWK

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I would like to store the values that I am able to print using the next code:

```
awk 'NR>1{printf "%2.4e  %2.4e  %2.4e %2.4e  %2.4e  %2.4e \n",$60, $61, $6\
6 , $67, $69, $70 }' RS='Step     10,' $1
```

The idea is to store them so I can compare them later on in the script. Is there any easy way of doing so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To store output from `awk` do

```
var=$(awk 'code' file)
```

This will store the output into a shell variable that you can use later.

If it gives multiple lines, remember to double quote when using the variable like this.
echo "$var"

To store data in an array do:

```
arr=($(awk 'code' file))
```

Comment: @_Jotne Can't I store every single field into a variable or in an array?

Comment: I would also suggest changing 'NR>1' to 'NR>70' too!

Comment: Which shell are you using?

Comment: @rivimey  `echo $SHELL
/bin/bash`

Comment: @rivimey why did you suggest `NR>70`? I cannot get it.

Comment: @Manolete As long as you store the data with some sort of separator you can store them to a single variable, and then later split it out to get every field.  Or you can store it to an array as I posted and get data out by `echo ${arr[0]}` `echo ${arr[1]}` `echo ${arr[2]}` etc.

Comment: @Jotne  `arr=($(awk 'NR>1{printf "%2.4e  %2.4e  %2.4e %2.4e  %2.4e  %2.4e \n",$60, $61, $66 , $67, $69, $70 }' RS='Step     10,'  $1))`

Comment: @Manolete Should work.  Can you post the output of the `awk`? It would then be better to see how it would be stored.

Comment: @Jotne The output is `3.4830e-06  1.6505e-02  0.0000e+00 0.0000e+00  3.4830e-06  1.6505e-02`. However, I get no value when I print `arr`

Comment: Okay, it works. Somehow I was testing `NR>70` and it is obvious that it does not work. It works with `NR>1`

Comment: @Manolete This works for me. `arr=(3.4830e-06  1.6505e-02  0.0000e+00 0.0000e+00  3.4830e-06  1.6505e-02)` `echo ${arr[0]}` gives `3.4830e-06` `echo ${arr[4]}` gives `3.4830e-06`